# PHP singleton pattern

Tags: php, oop, class, singleton, return

Hello there i want to learn a singleton pattern in php,
i have a class:

```
class Database
{
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() 
    { 
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$instance)
        {
            self::$instance= new Database();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function query($table)
    {
         $this->query = 'select * from $table';
    }

    public function result()
    {
        echo $this->query;

    }

}


$db = Database::getInstance();
```

and now , is it posible to call the result() method and print the value set by the query() which is "select * from $table" using a singleton?

i want my code in  something like:

```
$db->query('user_tb')->result();

//output
select * from user_tb;
```

Comment: little extra reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Comment: Please watch ["Singletons and global state"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI).

Answer (score 4):

### Update:

To be able to call it like:

```
$db->query('user_tb')->result();
```

You need to put `return $this;` in method you want to chain, in this case your `query` method:

```
public function query($table)
{
     $this->query = "select * from $table";
     return $this;
}
```

Now you can call it like : `$db->query('user_tb')->result();`

### [Working Example](http://codepad.org/jfxVE0gi)

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

First modify in your `query()` method:

```
$this->query = 'select * from $table';
```

To:

```
$this->query = 'select * from ' . $table;
```

since inside `single quotes`, variables are not parsed.

And then define `$query` at class level like this:

```
class Database {
  private static $Instance;
  private $query = '';
  // your more code
}
```

And then you can run this to get it:

```
$db = Database::getInstance(); // get class instance
$db->query('user_tb'); // set $query var
$db->result(); // get $query var
```

**Result:**

```
select * from user_tb
```

---

### [Working Example](http://codepad.org/FGH2O5Rq)

Comment: yes thanks, i did that approach actually but for some reason i want to do a series of coding style like i stated,  $db->query('user_tb')->result();

//output
select * from user_tb;

Comment: working example links are not working. please update it

Answer (score -1):

To use method chaining, make sure all functions you want to chain return $this.

Then you can do `DB::getInstance()->query()->result();`.=

So query at least needs to return $this.

Also, you forgo any error handling by return parameter, so generally if you use method chaining you need to use exception handling to deal with errors.

As in, you can't do

```
if(!$db->query) {
    error_log('bleh');
}
```

Comment: is there any way to return the instance automatically without returning $this inside each method?